# Google map markers too big

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

here is my code below, i choose an image to represent my marker and the image are way too big, is there a sort of way i can resize my image too look smaller e.g. padding, imagesizeicon and so on

```
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: center
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

for (var i=0; i<a.length;i++)
{
if(i == 0) iconImage = "image1.jpg";
else if(i == 1)  iconImage = "image2.jpg";
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:map,
      draggable:true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: a[i],
icon: iconImage,
  });
```

Comment: how big is your marker icons? pixel wise?

Comment: 256 pixel, does the pixel affect it?

Comment: yes it does typically makers are 32px by 32px or 20px by 34px ie http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png

Comment: so what can i do to make my image smaller?

Comment: open it in a image editing software and make it smaller?

Comment: okay, so what size nd pixel should i make it to be

Comment: make it 32px by 32px if you can..

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps-api-2?  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with that version of the API.  Please delete that tag (or answer so someone can remove it).

Comment: @geocodezip I removed the google-maps-api-2 tag (also not sure about the php tag)

Comment: you should also check out using svg paths for your icons.  the maps api has some sample code for that, you can easily scale your icons on the fly if they are vector paths.  `var iconImage = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeWeight: 14
  };`

Answer (score 8):

Use a [google.maps.icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) object to specify the icon instead of the simple image file name. There you can set the [size](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Size), e.g.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: a[i],
    icon: {
        size: new google.maps.Size(width, height),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(width, height),
        url: iconImage 
    },
});
```

---

Full working example (you need a `marker.gif` file next to this html document)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 11,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3727, 4.8985),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3727, 4.8985),
          icon: {
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
            url: "marker.gif"
          }
        });

      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user2116287 I added a full working example. Have a look at it.